# How do I get the latest version in my Entity Framework query that has an include

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following tables:

Site:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | site1 |
| 2 | Site2 |

Project:

| ID | Version | ProjectName | SiteId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Test1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Test2 | 1 |

Where `Id` and `Version` are primary keys.

I want to get a site and its newest projects.

My current best solution is as follows:

```cs
var sitesFirst = await context.Sites.AsNoTracking().Include(s => s.UserRelations).ToListAsync();

foreach (var site in sitesFirst)
{
    var projects = await context.Projects.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(p => p.SiteId == site.Id)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
        .Select(grouping => grouping.OrderByDescending(p => p.Version).First())
        .ToListAsync();
    site.Projects = (List<Project>?)projects;
}

return sitesFirst;
```

Which is not optimal with the multiple round trips.

I've tried different approaches to grouping and order by descending, but often EF seems to complain that it cant translate it.

This is with EF6

Comment: Do you have DTO classes? EF6 will not allow to project to Entity type.

Comment: I don't. I will try and look into that

Answer (score 0):

If you have DTO class for example `SiteDto`, you can use `Select` to project into that class.

```cs
var latestProjects = context.Projects
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.SiteId, p.Id })
    .Select(grouping => grouping.OrderByDescending(p => p.Version).First());

var sitesFirst = await context.Sites
    .Select(s => new SiteDto
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        ... // other properties

        Projects = latestProjects
            .Where(p => p.SiteId == s.Id)
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();

return sitesFirst;
```